# How to disable WARN WatcherWebSocketListener: Exec Failure java.io.EOFException when job finished in spark on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have set up a jupyter notebook which runs a pyspark job on our kubernetes cluster in Spark Client mode; after some tinkering around I managed to get the job to run.

The communication between the driver and the executors, however, does not terminate cleanly; more specifically, when the executors are finished, they do not seem to maintain communication with the driver - the driver in the jupyter notebook keeps indicating

```
22/01/05 09:55:53 WARN WatcherWebSocketListener: Exec Failure
java.io.EOFException
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:61)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByte(RealBufferedSource.java:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readHeader(WebSocketReader.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame(WebSocketReader.java:101)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.loopReader(RealWebSocket.java:274)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:214)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

One solution seems to be to kill the spark context at the end of the notebook, but I guess this means that the containers will need to be created each time and it does not really facilitate a very interactive modus.

Is it possible to disable this warning somehow?

I'm working with Spark v3.2.0.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Any update on this?